# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ForgotPasswordController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

According to a project at Laravel, working at forgot your password I am using ResetPasswordController as you can see at the code below called route as route('user.forgot') but an error says that this controller does not exists.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
            Route::get('/profile', [
                'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
                'as' => 'user.profile'
            ]);
            Route::get('/forgot', [
                'uses' => 'ForgotPasswordController@getForgot',
                'as' => 'user.forgot'
            ]);
            Route::post('/forgot', [
                'uses' => 'ForgotPasswordController@postPassword',
                'as' => 'user.forgot'   
            ]);
            Route::get('/reset_password_form', [
                'uses' => 'ForgotPasswordController@getReset',
                'as' => 'user.reset_password_form'
            ]);
            Route::post('/reset_password_form', [
                'uses' => 'ForgotPasswordController@postResetPassword',
                'as' => 'user.reset_password_form'   
            ]);    
            Route::get('/logout', [
                'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
                'as' => 'user.logout'
            ]);
            Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
            Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
            Route::get('/verify/{token}','verifyController@verify')->name('verify');
        });
```

Comment: is there the same two 'user.forgot' as a name?

Comment: I get 404|not found

Comment: can you change one of them and try!! '```user.forgot```'

Comment: What are you mean by that? Change /forgot to user.forgot?

Comment: you have two same ```'as' => 'user.forgot'``` and same URL ```/forgot``` and what I mean, can u change one of them. I think there could be a problem.

Comment: I will try to change that.

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you very much for your time.